# Please why is the value of the triangle in this my codes = 0?

Tags: c#

Please kindly assist to look at the reason why the value of the triangle is not 15 but it is 0 in this my codes.
Thank you.
Gbenga Olanipekun

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // int a =3 + 6;
        // int b = 5 -7;
        // int a;
        // a =3 + 6;
        // b =5 + 7;
        // int a = 6
        // b =c +5;
        // v = b -j ;
        // double moneymadefromgames = 100000;
        // double totalprogrammers = 4;
        // double moneyperperson = moneymadefromgames / totalprogrammers; 
        // the formular for area of circle is pi * r ^ 2;
        // the formular for area of triagle is 1/2 b * h;
        float b = 5;
        float height = 6;
        double area = 1/2 *b *  height;
        Console.WriteLine("the areas of triagle is " + area);
        int score;
        int age;
        age = -89;
        score = 33;
        int loan;
        int credit;
        float radius = 4;
        float pi = 3.1415926536f; // the 'f' makes it a float literal instead of a double literal.
        float newarea = pi * radius * radius;
        // using the + operator with strings results in "concatenation".
        Console.WriteLine("The area of the circle is " + newarea + ".");
       loan = 2000;
        credit = 5000;
        float totalcost = 22.54F;
        float tipPercent = 0.18F;
        float tipAmount =  totalcost * tipPercent;
        double moneymadefromgames = 100000;
        double totalprogrammers = 4;
        double moneyperperson = moneymadefromgames / totalprogrammers;
        System.Console.WriteLine(moneyperperson);
        System.Console.WriteLine(score - age);
        System.Console.WriteLine("PRESS ANY key to exit");
        System.Console.WriteLine(loan + credit);
        System.Console.WriteLine(tipAmount);
        System.Console.Read();
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you hava specific query about one calculation, you should remove the irrelevant code from your question that is doing the other unrelated calculations

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is the division. You want to calculate `0.5 * b * height`. So if you were to enter 0.5 instead of 1/2, you would get 15.

What's happening here is integer division.

> For the operands of integer types, the result of the / operator is of an integer type and equals the quotient of the two operands rounded towards zero

[From the Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#integer-division)

When you divide two integer numbers, the program will ignore the remainder.
As 1/2 is 0.5, all that the integer division will return is 0, ignoring the .5 remainder.
To solve this issue, you need to make at least one of your numbers a *float/double* value by adding a remainder.
`1/2.0` or `1.0/2` or `1.0/2.0`.
Thus the result will be 0.5.

```
Console.WriteLine(1   / 2  );  // output: 0
Console.WriteLine(1   / 2.0);  // output: 0.5
Console.WriteLine(1.0 / 2  );  // output: 0.5
Console.WriteLine(1.0 / 2.0);  // output: 0.5
```

Comment: I think you mean 1/2 not 2/1 in there. It's too small a change for me to edit for you.

Comment: @moreON Thank you, you're right, I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the 1/2 value to 0.5 for area calculation. So it should `double area = 0.5 *b *  height;`. This is the reason why you are getting zero instead of actual value.

```
using System;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            float b = 5;
            float height = 6;
            double area = 0.5 *b *  height;
            Console.WriteLine("the areas of triagle is " + area);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

The areas of triangle is 15.

Here is the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: It may be helpful to explain why as well. `1` and `2` are integer literals. the `/` operator with with integer left and right operands produces an integer result that is the floor of the division ... Maybe also mention the other options: keep formula as is, but use float literals i.e. `1f / 2f * ...` or just divide by `2` the integer value at the end of the expression instead.